# jQuery UI how to avoid submit button getting css classes?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, class

I'm using jQuery UI with a custom theme, and I have an `<input type="submit">` element on my page. Since jQuery is around this button gets the jQuery UI look and feel - it is automagically added the css classes `ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default`.

How do I get rid of these ?
Want the button to be a plain old button without those classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons don't automatically get the classes set - you must be calling something like the following

```
$("button, input:submit, input:button").button();
```

you need to remove input:submit

Comment: You are correct, that was indeed the case. Thx. StackOverflow is da bomb.

Answer (score 2):

To change your button back to 'normal' style you could either use ManseUK's answer,
 or if you just want to restyle this button you can remove the three classes by adding

`$("#yourButtonID").removeClass("ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default")`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is that if you look in the `jquery-ui.js` file there will be a block comment that starts with something like: "jQuery-UI Button", delete that entire block from the start of the comment to the start of the next comment for another widget.

This solved the problem for me.